# wcf implementation

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0

I am analysing various technologies in asp.net for better usage to have all it benefits(such as code reuse, avoiding time consumption by knowing technology usage etc) . currently working with wcf implementation . where will i be using it more effectively ? any suggestions would be appreciated

thank you

Comment: I'm sorry can you rephrase the question? Its not clear, to me,  what you're looking for

Comment: i mean at what situation  wcf(indigo) can be used or implemented very aptly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be using WCF in scenarios where you need to transport data between logical layers in different physical layers.

For example, a client-server application that should stream data from the server to the client and viceversa.

Or a web application that exposes a Web Service API.

It's all about simplifying socket programming over TCP, UDP and other protocols on top of these like HTTP and SOAP.

If you need a networked solution, WCF is one of best ways of easly acquire good results in less time, and gain a configurable and easy to deploy, easy to host n-tier program.

Comment: then it mean that the wcf is only used for video streaming ,chatting,video chatting etc.. am i right? where else i can use it?

Comment: I wasn't talking about streaming, but about developing client-server applications and connected services like ones you suggested, social networking APIs, payment gateways, accounting servers, and so on. Do you want to develop a locally or externally connected service? WCF is for you.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is a programming model that allows the developer to create distributed systems that follow SOA.

If you are looking at a system which needs to be loosely coupled and if you as a developer want to control the flow of data between layers to a great extent then a WCF service is the one for you.

take a look at Wrox's Professional WCF Programming if you could. you will get a good know how

`Dinesh